# ListView doesn't appear at all

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm currently learning android development and I'm trying to get the ListView to work. However, the ListView does not even shows up on the graphical layout and the emulator. Eclipse doesn't spot any error with my code either and I'm not sure why it doesn't appear at all. Below are the java class file (Start.java) and the two xml files (start.xml & member_names_inflate.xml).

**Start.java**

```
public class Start extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener
{
    private static EditText nameText = null;
    private static Button nameAdd = null;
    private static final Vector<String> nameContent = new Vector<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.start);
            nameContent.add("Steve");
            nameContent.add("Larry");

            nameText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
            nameAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
            nameAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
            setListAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(this));
    }

    private static class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
            private LayoutInflater nameInflater;

            public ListViewAdapter(Context context)
            {
                    nameInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            }

            public int getCount()
            {
                    return nameContent.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position)
            {
                    return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position)
            {
                    return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup group)
            {
                    ListContent contents;

                    if(view == null)
                    {
                            view = nameInflater.inflate(R.layout.member_names_inflate, null);
                            contents = new ListContent();
                            contents.text = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.name_first);
                            contents.text.setCompoundDrawables(view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bullet), null, null, null);
                            view.setTag(contents);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            contents = (ListContent)view.getTag();
                    }

                    contents.text.setText(nameContent.get(position));
                    return view;
            }

            static class ListContent
            {
                    TextView text;
            }
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
            if(v == nameAdd)
            {
                    nameContent.add(nameText.getText().toString());
                    setListAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(this));
            }
    }
}
```

**start.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/splash_bg"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/splash_text"
    android:text="@string/sub" />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/grp_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/field1"
    android:lines="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/members"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/splash_text"
        android:text="@string/members" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/field2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**member_names_inflate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/inflate_root"
android:background="@color/splash_bg"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/inflate_sub"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_bullet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bullet" />"

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_first"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/splash_text"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:text="@+id/name_first" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue I see is in your first nested `LinearLayout`

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

try changing that to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

You don't have room for anything else because you are telling it to take up all of the `height`.

Also note that `fill_parent` is deprecated and you should use `match_parent` instead. This isn't a problem but could be in the future. `LinearLayout` has a `horizontal orientation` by default so you don't need to declare that but it doesn't hurt to do it...just an FYI on that

Comment: I just tested this and it shows up in the editor with these changes.